# Перевод в северную, южную широту и западную, восточную долготу

Tags: python, координаты

У меня есть формулы перевода из декартовых координат в широту и долготу:

```
lat = math.asin(z / rZ)
lon = math.atan2(y, x)
```

Я так понимаю, что это общие формулы широты и долготы. Как разделить их на северную, южную широту и западную, восточную долготу.
Есть идеи?

Comment: "декартовых координат в картезианские" - может быть, Вы хотели сказать "артезианские"?

Comment: @Igor нет, так и хотел сказать "Картезианские"

Comment: А чем "декартовы" отличаются от "картезианских"?

Comment: очевиднo, что если есть формулы перевода с декартовых на картезианские и наоборот, то они чем-то да отличаются)

Comment: Они ничем не отличаются, это одно и то же. Привет от Декарта.

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать. Увидел ваш ответ, но как мне его использовать относительно формул?

Comment: Ещё стоит радианы в градусы/минуты перевести

Comment: да, они и так в градусах

Comment: @gleXXX латинское имя Рене Декарта - Ренатус Картезиус, по-русски - Картезий.

Comment: Спасибо. Буду знать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Положительная широта - северная, отрицательная - южная.

Положительная долгота - восточная, отрицательная - западная.

---

```
lat = math.asin(z / rZ)
latStr = str(abs(lat)) + ("радиан южной широты" if lat < 0 else " радиан северной широты")
```

Comment: Модуля math.abs нет в библиотеке python.

Comment: @gleXXXX Неужели? Какой еще питон?

Comment: Python — высокоуровневый язык программирования общего назначения, ориентированный на повышение производительности разработчика и читаемости кода. Синтаксис ядра Python минималистичен. В то же время стандартная библиотека включает большой набор полезных функций.

Comment: @gleXXXX Не валяйте дурака. Выяснить, как на питоне получить модуль числа, Вы можете сами.

Comment: вы имеете ввиду модуль числа Х, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @gleXXXX Нет, модуль числа Z.

Comment: Жаль, но в питоне нет модуля числа z, только x... `abs(x, /)`

Comment: т.е. широта - это Y, а долгота - это Х?

Comment: @vp_arth Значит, данная задача не имеет решения.

Comment: @gleXXXX Нет, широта это `lat` (latitude), долгота это `lon` (longitude).

Comment: я о том же. lat - Y, lon - X?

Comment: @gleXXXX Не портите впечатление. Я не понимаю, о чем Вы говорите.

Comment: остановимся на том, что эта задача не имеет решения.

Comment: @gleXXXX Чудесно. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.